# CSV Reading and parsing data

Tags: python, csv

This is my first question on stackoverflow.

I have example .csv file, with a lot of data.

FILE = r'C:\Users\jarxi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\docs_1\0ft1iosx.csv'

I want only specific data from file. Only digit and length = 10.

```
result = []
import csv
with open(FILE, mode='rt') as data:
    for line in csv.reader(data):
        pass
        for id_client in line:
            if id_client.isdigit() and len(id_client) == 10:
                result.append(id_client)
```

I saved specific data to list.

In folder a have a lot of .csv files.
Names of files should be key in dictionary. Specific data which I saved to list, should be list of values in dict.

`files = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\jarxi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\docs_1')`

Output:
`['0ft1iosx.csv', '0zh5dxuv.csv', '1bgt820k.csv', '1k2o9iin.csv', '1njzdjkf.csv', ...]`

`myDict = dict.fromkeys(files,[])`

`myDicy['0ft1iosx.csv'] = result`

Output:
`{'0ft1iosx.csv': ['8081288519', '6630847358', '8408154578', '3743147489', '8616408287', '7774656314', '9563069174', '1471973729', '9158586440', '6734824277'], '0zh5dxuv.csv': [], '1bgt820k.csv': [], '1k2o9iin.csv': [], '1njzdjkf.csv': [], ...}`

I want make the same operations for all files .csv in directory.
I think I should connect my code with for loop but I don't have idea.

**Desired Output with example data:**

`{'0ft1iosx.csv': ['8081288519', '6630847358', '8408154578', '3743147489', '8616408287', '7774656314', '9563069174', '1471973729', '9158586440', '6734824277'], '0zh5dxuv.csv': ['3743147489', '8616408287', '7774656314'], '1bgt820k.csv': ['6630847358', '8408154578', '3743147489'], '1k2o9iin.csv': ['1471973729'], '1njzdjkf.csv': ['9158586440', '6734824277'], ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question properly, then you just need to put your code that handles one file inside a `for` loop.

Here's what I mean:

```
import csv
import glob
import os


folder = r'C:\Users\jarxi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\docs_1'
mydict = {}

for filepath in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*.csv')):
    results = []
    with open(filepath, mode='r', newline='') as csv_file:
        for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
            for field in row:
                if field.isdigit() and len(field) == 10:
                    results.append(field)

    if results:  # Matches?
        key = os.path.basename(filepath)  # Filename only.
        mydict[key] = results
```